# Remainder without division

Tags: math, integer-division

I have already googled a lot about this topic and also have read similar questions and their respective answers.
What I'm asking about is a specific algorhitm for calculating mod 2**k+c (c can be negative). There are also some limitations about how big "c" can be.

I have seen some code at work where it was done (without division), but for some reason I can't properly google it.

P.S. Also have a second question about this topic, it's related enough, so not worth creating another topic. I'm using Montgomery multiplication, but I also want to optimize number convertation. I am familiar with "magic numbers" stuff that used for optimizations and I also have found this calculator.
http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm

Is there a way to adapt it to much bigger numbers? Like hundreds of bits. Divisor is known at compile time.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the limitations on the value of `c`? Can the algorithm be limited to 32-bit or 64-bit integers?

Comment: Algorithm should work for any value of `k`, I think. Not sure about `c`, it's probably limited to one limb of big integer (32/64). I'd also like to find out the limitation.

Comment: Consider [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/852.pdf) as a starting point, and follow both the paper and the references in it. 2^k - c are referred to a Crandall numbers.